# How to restart only Apple Watch app when debugging?

Tags: debugging, xcode6, apple-watch

I am trying to debug using the Apple Watch simulator. It works fine when I start the app -- awakeWithContext() runs and works correctly, except there's no data yet.

I need to test testawakeWithContext() after the user has navigated to a specific place in the iOS app (because there's more data to get).

Is there a way to restart the Apple Watch app without restarting the iOS app in the simulator? The only alternative I've thought of is to put a temporary button on the Watch app that will call awakeWithContext(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a terminal, you can kill the running process for your watch app and then relaunch it.

```
kill -9 <pid of your watch app>
xcrun simctl launch booted <identifier of your watch app>
```